# NetworkX cmap not having any effect on node colour

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to visualise communities in a node network using networkx, the code is working fine in terms of detecting the communities however it is in greyscale. I have been unable to get the cmap parameter to have any effect on the output network when used in conjunction with nodelist and node_color parameters.

Current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq8T3.png

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import community

g=nx.read_edgelist('communities.txt',create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype=int)

partition = community.best_partition(g)

print nx.info(g)

size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
print "Communities: " + str(size)

sp=nx.spring_layout(g)
plt.axis('off')

count = 0
for group in set(partition.values()) :
    count += 1
    list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys() if partition[nodes] == group]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos=sp,
        nodelist=list_nodes,
        with_labels=False,
        node_size=30,
        node_color = str(count/size),
        cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu'))


nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, sp, alpha=0.3)
plt.show(g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `cmap` option to work, `node_color` must be a list of floating-point numbers, not a string. Also, `vmin` and `vmax` options must be provided. The numeric values are mapped to colors using the `cmap` and `vmin` and `vmax` parameters. (See `help(nx.draw_networkx_nodes)`.)

Comment: (was rewriting my comment just now, sorry for cross-deleting):  Could you add the quote: "If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and vmin,vmax parameters." to the answer?

Comment: @Joel I do not believe this adds much to the answer, but ok.